# Macro that finds value given 3 conditions

Tags: excel, vba, output

I need help creating a macro that finds a value given 3 conditions, year, quarter and color. I realize that the easiest way to solve this is by creating a pivot table, but I was asked to solve this using a macro.

Here is what the table looks like, I need to be able to find the value in C12 given the conditions around it.

[image: table]

I appreciate your time and any advice would be pleasantly taken.

Comment: use the AND() function to test for 3 items...

Comment: Use `Find()` to locate the year, then another `Find()` in the row below to locate the quarter.  You can also use Find() to match the third item.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following formula for the worksheet in your question.

```
=OFFSET($B$2,MATCH($B$12,$B$2:$B$7,0)-1,MATCH($C$11,OFFSET($C$3:$F$3,0,MATCH($C$10,$2:$2,0)-COLUMN($B$2)-1),0)+MATCH($C$10,$2:$2,0)-COLUMN($B$2)-1)
```